# Swift framework on Xamarin.iOS - Foundation.MonoTouchException has been thrown

Tags: c#, swift, binding, xamarin.ios

**Xamarin iOS app was crashed while running swift framework.**

*In my .framework - Swift class*

```
import Foundation

@objc(Member)
open class Member: NSObject {

    @objc
    func getMemberID() -> String {
        return "Hii, This is member code .framework"
    }
}
```

I have build a framework for *simulator iPhone7* and added in *Native framework* on **Visual studio Xamarin.iOS**

And I have coded manually for interface class.

```
using System;

using ObjCRuntime;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace CustomLibrary {

    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
    interface Member
    {
        [Export("getMemberID")]
        string MemberID { get; }
    }
}
```

After that I have add reference for Binding library to iOS App project.

[image]

In ViewController I have imported a *Binding library* and allocate a class and print in log.

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using CustomLibrary;

namespace SwiftFrameworkApp
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            Member memberObj = new Member();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(memberObj.MemberID());
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
    }
}
```

When I build a project. Its was shown

> Errors 0 and warning 1

[image]

After that When I run a project. App was launched in simulator and crashed with below error.

[image]

Comment: You should implement the getmemberID() in the member interface. See the stacktrace, getmemberID() can't be found in the project.

Comment: In my project I have already implemented getmemberID() Please check code on question

Comment: The  getmemberID() in swift is a method while you convert it into a property in Xamarin.iOS. You should bind it as a method too. See here:[binding-methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries?context=xamarin%2Fios&tabs=windows#binding-methods)

Comment: Does it works for you?

Comment: Yes, Its working fine. But I have to present a ViewController from .framework on Xamarin.iOS App

Comment: So, can you please mark it as the answer so that we can help more people with same problem.  If you have problem with presenting a ViewController from .framework on Xamarin.iOS App, you can open a new thread and add your code there, we will support you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean in your `Member` interface, it should be something like this:

```
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface Member
{
    [Export("getMemberID")]
    string GetMemberID ();
}
```